# Implementing a breadth first search with rxjs Observables

Tags: angular, algorithm, rxjs, logic

The thing I'm trying to implement isn't exactly a breadth first search, but it's similar in how a common breadth first search would be implemented. When trying to find the shortest path using a breadth first search, you start with a queue that has a starter node, pop off that node, and add that node's children to the queue, continuing the loop. When you find the end node you're looking for, you stop execution/popping stuff off the queue.

What I'm trying to do is have an outer Observable that can be subscribed to. When someone subscribes it'll start a base queue of inner Observables. As those observables get ran, they will add other observables to the queue of inner observables. If the value/scenario I'm looking for gets reached at some point during an observable execution, I want to emit that value and complete the outer observable. If no value/scenario is found, I want to emit `null` and complete the outer observable. Do people have any suggestions of built in rxjs magic I could use to accomplish something like this? I've been looking at [queueScheduler](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/queueScheduler) which I think may be helpful, but I don't know how I would return `null` when I run out of events. I need it to complete by itself when there's nothing left on the queue, then trigger so I can complete the outer observable for the subscriber. I also want to cancel any queued actions if I find the value/scenario I want.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can get most of what you're looking for by combining the usual rxjs operators (`concat`, `switchMap`) etc. When the subscription is unsubscribed it will unsubscribe from each observable in turn, so the producer doesn't really need to know that the consumer has found the value it's looking for.

I've written an example [on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-fnwxum?file=index.ts).
Using the `filter`, `take(1)` and `toArray` operators, it will emit either the found value as a singleton array or an empty array and then complete.